# Weird join issue in MS Access ... first value returning all the values, rather than just the match

Tags: ms-access

I have a very weird issue that has stumped me (and my colleagues at work). Here's what's happening:

I have two tables, one that has my main dataset (tblExpenses) and one that has a list of fifteen values for a lookup (tblCompanies). They are joined on a field called [CompanyID], which is a text field set to 5 characters (this matches in both tables, and it's the primary key in tblCompanies, is indexed and unique).

My query is set up to look up [SpendCategory] from tblCompanies based on [CompanyID]. Currently I have this set up as an inner join (which should work). But the first value in tblExpenses always returns all 15 values from tblCompanies (as a stacked set of values, which concatenates into a long string when exported into Excel). Subsequent [CompanyID] values return only the matching [SpendCategory]. My query also appends "SP_" before the spend category. My results look something like this (I've concatenated the stacked values here for space ... it's what my exported Excel spreadsheet looks like)

| CompanyID | SpendCategory |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | SP_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO |
| 00001 | SP_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO |
| 00010 | SP_B |
| 00500 | SP_K |

I have tried:

- an outer join (all of tblExpenses and only matching from tblCompanies); both return the same result.
- changing my primary and secondary key to a number field instead of text; both return the same result.
- changing the order of tblExpenses, but whatever value is in the first row gets the "all results" treatment all the way down the list, and all the other values are fine.
- taking out the addition of "SP_" ... but that doesn't change anything either.

Can anyone think of something I could try? Has anyone seen something like this before?

Thanks in advance for any words of wisdom.

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data and the SQL statement. What do you mean by 'concatenated the stacked values here for space' - exactly what does the query output look like? Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I can think of checking if the property "Allow Multiple Values" is set  to Yes in any of the involved fields. This is one of the properties of drop-down menus.